# How do I bundle, minify and transpile JavaScript code using ASP.NET bundleConfig.cs

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, babeljs, minify

I have an old ASP.NET site which using using the built in bundling and minification  using the bundleConfig.cs

This is great, however when I have added some ES6 syntax to my JavaScript it no longer minifies correctly.

Is there a way to transpile the code first before it is minified without having to install NodeJs and using Bable as per the following example?  Is there a way I can use Babel straight from the ASP.Net website before the files are minified?

https://www.slightedgecoder.com/2017/05/22/setting-es6-environment-asp-net-mvc-5/

The problem is I don't really want to have to convert every JavaScript file to have exportable functions etc as the code base is quite large.  Unless there is a way which I can export all the code in a JavaScript file in one go and import just the files into a new master js budle file?